# how to create jar file using gradle for spring boot web project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle

I have created spring boot web app project using gradle and it works perfectly fine in eclipse.But when I try to create Jar file and hit url from web browser the controller is called but the .jsp page is not render.
Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: using JSP in a JAR won't work, this is clearly documented in the reference guide. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations

Comment: Thanks for your kind replay.So what is the solution.My requirement is to provoid view where user can upload there .xlsx file And that is why i need some view technology for my application.

Comment: Use something like Thymeleaf instead.